# Can I texture one object part by part

Tags: texturing

I have a somewhat complex model like this. I made the whole building separately(top middle and lower part are different objects, fences and pillars are also different objects). I am just wondering what is the general way for making texture of this whole building. Do I do UV unwrapping one part by one part (I mean do the UV unwrap for pillar, and another UV unwrap for fences and so on) for texturing, or I UV unwrap the whole building into one picture, and use photoshop for texturing. This is the first time I do texturing for complex model like this, please offer me some experience and general steps. Thanks[image]

Comment: You can do both way. If you want to texture it with multiple images, assign different materials in edit mode to the different parts, and DO NOT create multiple UV maps.

Comment: Personally, I would keep the parts separate and texture them separately.  For me, it makes it a lot easier to manage and th change later if I want to.
Having said that, doing it all as one UV map is an equally good way of doing it.

Comment: @FFeller are you suggesting I cannot make one UV map for each separate part? Or I just cannot make different UV maps for the whole thing

Comment: Don't create multiple UVs in this tab: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/layout_management.html#multiple-uv-maps If you use multiple materials, every material's texture can use the whole UV area so the different material's uv islands overlaps each other. But every UV map contains the whole mesh, so it makes no sense to use multiple UV maps in this case.